# Making changes to Objects in a rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, relationship

I'd like to migrate a belongs_to relationship that I currently have to a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship. Ideally I'd like to do this in the migration that I've built.

When I add this new migration which is the join IDs for these two items, can I then afterwards make changes to the model in that Migration?

```
#migration code goes here to add the new item field
Item.find(:all).each do |item|
specific changes to item to account for the new relationship
end
```

Or is that not something I can do within that rake environment? I'd like to migrate the objects over to using the new HABTM system, will I have to check for that in the actual code itself and run that as a separate rake task before launching the instance of the application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is perfectly fine. Although it can take a lot of time if you are upgrading and require changes to be made, the migration is an acceptable place to do it.